# Laravel: load images stored indise 'storage' folder

Tags: php, mysql, image, laravel

I'm trying to display an image stored inside the 'storage' folder, for protected the images folder. how I should do it for 2 parameters, it does not work well this code below:

route :

```
Route::get('img/users/{id}/logo/{image}', function($id = null, $image = null)
{
    $path = storage_path().'/img/profils/'.$id.'/logo/'.$image;
    if (file_exists($path)) { 
        return Response::download($path);
    } 
});
```

view:

```
src="{!!asset('img/users/'.$user->id.'/logo/'.$user->imagelogo)!!}"
```

Comment: post the errors

Comment: how, I did not understand?

Comment: I cannot get the image by profile, but if I do like this, set the id of the user, it displays the image profile : Route::get('img/users/2/logo/{image}', function($id = null, $image = null)
{
    $path = storage_path().'/img/profils/2/logo/'.$image;

Answer (score 0):

I had done this, but not using your way. What I did was,

Save the image in `public` folder.

Then created a custom `css` and used

```
.your div tag id {
width: 100%; //px you need
height: auto;
padding: 100px 0;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
background: url(../your image.jpg);
background-color: #000;
 }
```

I think using this inside a `<panel>` will give you a solution.

Comment: Please, can you give me more explanation?

Comment: where do you need to post this image? side bar or something like that?

Comment: I want to protect all images in the folder.

Comment: I dont know why you want to use `Route::get` method for doing this.

Comment: do you have another solution?

Comment: sorry, no.this is what i used.